# Make a conditional in a JDialog

Tags: java, jpanel, jdialog

I'm trying to put a conditional in a JDialog which detect if the two buttons in it are disabled. I need that also to close the dialog when it reach this condition so I found 2 problems. Example code:

```
    public static String windowvisitAlert(JButton but, JButton but2, String message1, String message2) throws Exception, Exception {
    String n = "";
    Object[] options = {but, but2};
    Object a = message1;
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(a, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, options, options[0]);
    JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(message2);
    dialog.setContentPane(pane);
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setSize(new Dimension(450, 10));
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    return n;
}
```

This is the method which creates a JDialog from a JPanel options. We have 2 buttons and 2 "messages" which only determinates the name of the dialog window.

I tried to put :

```
if (but.isEnabled()==false && but2.isEnabled()==false) {
dialog.setVisible(false);
}else{
dialog.setVisible(true);}
```

Also this method will return the value n so I don't know how will a condition work inside it.

Where i implement this method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    final JButton but = new JButton("VISITA");
                    final JButton but2 = new JButton("RESPONSABLE");
                    try {

                        ActionListener actionListener2 = new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                                //action performed
                            }

                        };
                        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                                //action performed
                            }

                        };
                            but.addActionListener(actionListener2);
                            but2.addActionListener(actionListener);
                            Alerts.windowvisitAlert(but, but2, Gui.getProperties().getProperty("text"), Gui.getProperties().getProperty("text"));

                    }catch (Exception ex) {
                        sc.functionSavingInLog(Utils.getClassInfo(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]), ex.toString());
                        System.out.println(Utils.getClassInfo(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]) + ex);
                    }
                    }
```

This is actually not working so my question is:

-How can I make this condition work and make the JDialog close when it hits it?

If not, how can I change the method or just do a jpanel?

Comment: How do the buttons become disabled?

Comment: They become disable in another class which is called inside each actionPerformed